# How to append data over loops

Tags: python, loops, append

```
for file in image_chunk:
    temp = mat73.loadmat(file)['image'] 
    print(temp.shape)


(10, 20, 3, 1000)
(10, 20, 3, 2000)
(10, 20, 3, 3000)
```

I have some data like this, I wanted to append or concatenate over the fourth dimension.
how can I do that?

My result will be (10, 20, 3, 6000)

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a numpy array and do this:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[10, 20, 3, 1000],
   [10, 20, 3, 2000],
   [10, 20, 3, 3000]])

  
print(np.sum(a[:,3]))
```

Edit- Since you changed your answer,

```
b=np.sum(a[:,3])
a[:,3]=b
print(a[1])

for i in range(len(a)-1):
   a=np.delete(a,i,0)
print(a)
```

to get your results